# Saving a picture from a browser canvas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, flash, canvas, paint

I'm currently developing a website in ASP .NET MVC and I require functionality for a user to be able to draw a picture on a canvas which can be saved in a database. What is the best method for doing this? preferably a very lightweight solution. I was thinking flash would be the most accessible platform and there may be some good free solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash can do it pretty easily, though you'll have to get your back-end set up to enable it. Basically you can draw anything on your stage to a bytearray of pixel data, then encode that bytearray to comply with for instance the .PNG specification. Then you send the whole package over to your back end as a byte array and make sure that your server-side scripts know to write it as a .png file to your server, then save the location in your database. Does that make sense?

A broad example can be found here on the Flex Cookbook: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Creating_a__png_file_from_a_webcam_image-12732.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in DotNet using the canvas.

```
canvas.SaveAs(dstfile, "Quality=high");
```

Here is the tutorial: http://www.websupergoo.com/helpig6net/source/3-examples/1-drawimage.htm

No need to use Flash.

Comment: I think the question is referring to the `<canvas />` tag in HTML5, not the `Canvas` class in .NET. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial

Answer (score 1):

An excellent way of saving an image is to use the native `toDataURL` method.

```
var element = document.getElementById('drawingCanvas');
var data = element.toDataURL();
// data holds the base64 encoded image of the canvas
```

From there you can post it asynchronously to the server

```
$.ajax({
    'type': 'post',
    'dataType': 'json',
    'data': {'image': data},
    'url': '/json/image_converter.php'
});
```

and convert it to an image using ImageMagick:

```
list($header, $data) = explode(',', $_POST['image']);
$image = base64_decode($data);

$magick = new Imagick();
$magick->setFormat('png');

$magick->readImageBlob($image);

$magick->writeImage('/home/dude/imagefile.png');
```

Edit: Oh, and of course I forgot to say that IE doesn't support canvas, hence no toDataURL method. Even with explorer canvas workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this in Silverlight... Silverlight should be able to, without difficulty, translate the mouse movements into line strokes.  I don't know if there is a pure JavaScript solution too.

Answer (score 0):

User MouseUp,mouseDown and MouceMove events along with LintTo,MoveTO events of canvas (all javascript) to draw a picture and then use canvas.toDataURL() to save this picture in a base64 string in yr database.